# JSONArray adding unwanted quotation marks to geoJSON

Tags: java, json, string, geojson

I am attempting to have my Java program write its output to a geoJSON file. Something like the following works well

```
JSONArray coord = new JSONArray("["+obj.getLng()+","+obj.getLat()+"]");
point.put("coordinates", coord);
```

generates the following correct JSON String

```
"coordinates":[-105.93879779882633,36.29086585830942]
```

However, I would also like to include lines (and polygons) in my output. These are defined as collections of coordinates, such that the resulting string looks something like this

```
"coordinates":[[-106.0,36.0],[-105.96856743366506,36.0],[-105.93713486733012,36.0]]
```

I am attempting to read a collection of points that define my line into a JSONArray. However, no matter what I do, there ends up being extra quotation marks in my final JSON String. Something like

```
"coordinates":["[-106.0,36.0],[-105.96856743366506,36.0],[-105.93713486733012,36.0]"]
```

if I try to use StringBuilder to build out the exact content of the string I would like the coordinates value to hold. If I attempt to create an array of coordinate arrays and give that to the JSONArray constructor, I simply end up with each coordinate pair in quotation marks instead.

My question is: Why is it that using StringBuilder or other methods to create my JSONArray leads to this result, but directly passing in a String to the new JSONArray constructor does not? The JSONArray constructor seems perfectly capable of interpreting

```
new JSONArray("["+obj.getLng()+","+obj.getLat()+"]");
```

correctly, but falls apart when I say

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Obj obj : objs) {
builder.append("["+obj.getLng()+","+obj.getLat()+"]");
} 
new JSONArray(builder.toString());
```

This seems like a trivial problem, so the solution to my issue is likely simple, but I would particularly like help in understanding why this is the case.

**Example**:

```
JSONObject point = new JSONObject();
JSONArray coord = new JSONArray("["+150+","+30+"]");
point.put("coordinates", coord);
System.out.println(point.toString());
```

results in

```
{"coordinates":[150,30]}
```

however

```
JSONObject lineString = new JSONObject();
String[] coords = {"["+150+","+30+"],["+160+","+40+"],["+170+","+50+"]"};
JSONArray coord = new JSONArray(coords);
lineString.put("coordinates", coord);
System.out.println(lineString.toString());
```

results in

```
{"coordinates":["[150,30],[160,40],[170,50]"]}
```

The issue is the quotation marks surrounding the cords string array ({"coordinates":[**-->"**[150,30],[160,40],[170,50]**"<--**]})

Comment: Where are you appending the commas? Where are the outer brackets? Please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can identify the problem.

Comment: Your example is very different from your question, but it does make it pretty obvious why you're getting your results.

Answer (score 1):

`coords` needs to just be a JSONArray *as a string*.

There's not extra quotes. You've made a list of one string.

So like

```
String coords = "["+150+","+30+"]";
JSONArray coordArray = new JSONArray(coords);
```

Which seems to match your first example, and that is correct, so I don't see the confusion since you're doing different things.

Anyways, it would be best to use the JSONArray methods to build the array rather than messing with string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, A `JSONArray` contains many other `JSONArray`.
So we have to write code accordingly.

E.g.:

```
JSONArray cooord = new JSONArray();     
for (Obj obj : objs) {
    JSONArray temp = new JSONArray();
    temp.put(obj.getLng());
    temp.put(obj.getLat()+);

    cooord.put(temp);
}

System.out.println(cooord);
```